# can "perf record" or "perf-record" sample child processes?

Tags: linux-kernel, perf

Assume I have a harness binary which could spawn different benchmarks according to command line option. I am really interested in sampling these benchmarks.

I have 3 options:

1. change the harness binary to spawn a `perf record` child process which run the benchmarks and do the sampling
2. just do `perf record $harness-binary` hoping it will sample the child process too.
3. `perf record -a $harness-binary` which would do a "System-wide collection from all CPUs.". This requires root access, therefore not feasible in my case.

Approach #2 is clean if perf-record really samples the child process. Can somebody help to confirm if this is the case? Pointers to documents or perf code would be highly appreciated.

If approach #2 is feasible and the benchmarks is much more CPU-intensive than the harness, I think the quality of the benchmark sampling should be reasonably good, right?

Thanks

Comment: Similar question about `perf stat -p $PID` to attach to an existing process, but then follow its threads.  [How to count number of executed instructions of a process id including all future child threads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64076497)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`perf record` without `-a` option record all processes, forked (and threads cloned) from target process after starting of record. With `perf record ./program` it will profile all child processes too, and with `perf record -p $PID` with attaching to already running $PID it will profile target process and all child processes started after attaching. Profiling inheritance is enabled by default (code as required: [`attr->inherit        = !opts->no_inherit;`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.8/source/tools/perf/util/evsel.c#L809) & [no_inherit](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.8/source/tools/perf/builtin-record.c#L1639)) and can be disabled with `-i` option and also disabled by `-t` and `--per-thread`.

This inheritance is like in `perf stat`: https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial

> Counting and inheritance
>
> By default, perf stat counts for all threads of the process and subsequent child processes and threads. This can be altered using the -i option. It is not possible to obtain a count breakdown per-thread or per-process.

And `-i` option is there for `perf record` too: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-record.1.html

> ```
>   -i, --no-inherit
>       Child tasks do not inherit counters.
> ```

`perf report` can filter events from some PID from collected combined perf.data file.

Comment: is there any similar solution for `perf stat`?

Comment: There is man page for perf stat: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-stat.1.html and it does mention same option:    "`-i, --no-inherit`  child tasks do not inherit counters"