# How to count number of executed instructions of a process id including all future child threads

Tags: linux, performance, profiling, performance-testing, perf

Some times ago, I asked the following question ["How to count number of executed instructions of a process id including child processes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62851367/how-to-count-number-of-executed-instructions-of-a-process-id-including-child-pro), and @M-Iduoad kindly provided a solution with `pgrep` to capture all child PIDs and use it with -p in perf stat. It works great!

However, one problem I encountered is with multi-threaded application, and when a new thread is being spawned. Since I'm not a fortune teller (too bad!), I don't know `tid` of the newly generated threads, and therefore I can't add them in the `perf stat`'s -p or -t parameter.

As an example, let's assume I have a multithreaded nodejs server (deployed as a container on top of Kubernetes) with the following `pstree`:

```
root@node2:/home/m# pstree -p 4037791
node(4037791)─┬─sh(4037824)───node(4037825)─┬─{node}(4037826)
              │                             ├─{node}(4037827)
              │                             ├─{node}(4037828)
              │                             ├─{node}(4037829)
              │                             ├─{node}(4037830)
              │                             └─{node}(4037831)
              ├─{node}(4037805)
              ├─{node}(4037806)
              ├─{node}(4037807)
              ├─{node}(4037808)
              ├─{node}(4037809)
              ├─{node}(4037810)
              ├─{node}(4037811)
              ├─{node}(4037812)
              ├─{node}(4037813)
              └─{node}(4037814)
```

Of course, I can have the following `perf stat` command to watch its threads:

```
perf stat --per-thread -e instructions,cycles,task-clock,cpu-clock,cpu-migrations,context-switches,cache-misses,duration_time -p $(pgrep --ns 4037791 | paste -s -d ",")
```

It works fine with a single threaded nodejs application. But in case of a multi-threaded service, as soon as it receives a request, the `pstree` output would be look like this:

```
root@node2:/home/m# pstree -p 4037791
node(4037791)─┬─sh(4037824)───node(4037825)─┬─{node}(4037826)
              │                             ├─{node}(4037827)
              │                             ├─{node}(4037828)
              │                             ├─{node}(4037829)
              │                             ├─{node}(4037830)
              │                             ├─{node}(4037831)
              │                             ├─{node}(1047898)
              │                             ├─{node}(1047899)
              │                             ├─{node}(1047900)
              │                             ├─{node}(1047901)
              │                             ├─{node}(1047902)
              │                             ├─{node}(1047903)
              │                             ├─{node}(1047904)
              │                             ├─{node}(1047905)
              │                             ├─{node}(1047906)
              │                             ├─{node}(1047907)
              │                             ├─{node}(1047908)
              │                             ├─{node}(1047909)
              │                             ├─{node}(1047910)
              │                             ├─{node}(1047911)
              │                             ├─{node}(1047913)
              │                             ├─{node}(1047914)
              │                             ├─{node}(1047919)
              │                             ├─{node}(1047920)
              │                             ├─{node}(1047921)
              │                             └─{node}(1047922)
              ├─{node}(4037805)
              ├─{node}(4037806)
              ├─{node}(4037807)
              ├─{node}(4037808)
              ├─{node}(4037809)
              ├─{node}(4037810)
              ├─{node}(4037811)
              ├─{node}(4037812)
              ├─{node}(4037813)
              └─{node}(4037814)
```

Therefore, my previous `perf stat` command would not capture the stats of the newly generated threads. I mean, it may capture accumulated instructions but it's definitely not showing in a "per-thread" format.

Is there any way that I can use `--per-thread` in perf stat and capture stats of the newly spawned threads in a multithreaded application?  It seems to only work with `-p` or `-t` to follow a fixed set of threads that already exist when `perf` starts, and won't follow new ones.

---

There's a similar [question here for `perf record`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44866699/can-perf-record-or-perf-record-sample-child-processes) but I'm using `perf stat`.  Also, that doesn't seem to separate the recorded profile by thread, so it's just equivalent to `perf stat node ...`  Unless there's a way to process the recorded data to separate it out by thread after the fact?

---

#### `perf` isn't a requirement if there's something else that works:

Any other potential solutions that help me dynamically count "instructions,cycles,task-clock,cpu-clock,cpu-migrations,context-switches,cache-misses" per threads of a given PID (including newly spawned threads) is acceptable, whether using `perf` or anything else!

Comment: `perf stat` without `-p` does trace all threads.  e.g. `perf stat node foo.js`, same as in that linked `perf record` question.  Your problem is getting perf to do what when you use `-p` instead of running the command as a child of `perf`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I tried without -p and with --per-thread, but it's still not reporting newly forked/spawned threads after perf start :-( ... in other words, inherit mode seems to be off

Comment: `perf stat ffmpeg -i foo.mkv bar.mkv` works for me.  I see `190,958.96 msec task-clock 
# 7.027 CPUs utilized` (on my 4c8t Skylake system), with 27.17 secs of elapsed wall-clock time.  (After pressing `q` to stop early.)  And the other counts, for HW events, reflect counts across all threads started by FFmpeg, for libx264, and for audio encode.

Comment: @PeterCordes Could you see each individual thread's executed instructions? (not accumulated instructions count, but instead, separate statistics per each thread) - and also try with -p instead - or at least for all threads/processes running on the system, since in my scenario, I have a running Kubernetes container and I should either use -p or get stats for all threads/processes and parse it myself afterwards

Comment: Oh, no `perf stat --per-thread` only works with `-p` or `-t`, sorry.  It says that in an error message if I try `perf stat --per-thread ffmpeg ...`.  You might need to send a feature-request for `perf` to implement this, or hack it up yourself.  It might possibly be fairly easily if the `perf record` equivalent does exactly what you're looking for in terms of following new threads but still keeping stats for each separately.

Comment: @PeterCordes All I need is to count number of instruction and cycles per each thread. I played with `perf record` a lot, but couldn't get anything as good as perf stat. There is a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62550369/run-perf-stat-on-the-output-of-perf-record

Comment: I didn't mean *actually* use `perf record`.  I was asking if `perf record --per-thread` really did  record `perf.data` outputs for each thread separately, i.e. whether it was doing per-thread profiling while following new threads like you want.  If `perf record` can do it, teaching `perf stat` to do it, too would hopefully not be much of a problem.

Comment: @PeterCordes I couldn't to get any per-thread statistics for a given `-e` events with `perf record` (especially instructions and cycles). I'm not sure if it's actually possible with `perf record`, but it would be great if I find a way to do it with `record` instead of `stat`...

Comment: Ok, I was afraid of that; [can "perf record" or "perf-record" sample child processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44866699) that you linked *isn't* actually a perf-record equivalent of what you want.  So just being for `perf record` isn't the only difference between that and your question.

Comment: Have you tried to `perf record` with `-s` to include per thread stats, and then read the perf.data with `perf report -T` you'll get a table at the bottom with threads and their stats.

Comment: @M.Iduoad I tried that before, it's not reporting information that I need.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for your great edits, question looks much better now :-)

Comment: To get the number of instructions per thread, you can use Intel pin tool called inscount2_mt provided in SimpleExamples folder of Intel PIN distribution. Measurement of instruction count should be more accurate than *sampled perf record measurements*. While it is possible to collect other information using rdpmc instruction as part of *docount* function in the code, there is *no way to tell whether the readings are particular to a thread*. Measurements would be particular to a core.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The combination of `perf record -s` and `perf report -T` should give you the information you need.

To demonstrate, take the following example code using threads with well-defined instruction counts:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <thread>

void work(int64_t count) {
    for (int64_t i = 0; i < count; i++);
}

int main() {
    std::thread first(work, 100000000ll);
    std::thread second(work, 400000000ll);
    std::thread third(work, 800000000ll);
    first.join();
    second.join();
    third.join();
}
```

(Compile without optimization!)

Now, use `perf record` as a prefix command. It will follow all spawned processes and threads.

```
$ perf record -s -e instructions -c 1000000000 ./a.out
[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.003 MB perf.data (5 samples) ]
```

To display the statistics nicely:

```
$ perf report -T
[... snip ...]
#    PID     TID  instructions:u
  270682  270683       500003888
  270682  270684      2000001866
  270682  270685      4000002177
```

The parameters for `perf record` are a little bit tricky. `-s` writes separate records with fairly precise numbers - they do not depend on the instruction samples (generated every 1000000000 instructions). However, `perf report`, even with `-T` fails when it does not find a single sample. So you need to set a instruction sample count `-c` (or frequency) that triggers at least once. Any sample will do, it does not need a sample per thread.

Alternatively, you could look at the raw records from `perf.data`. Then you can actually tell `perf record` to not collect *any* samples.

```
$ perf record -s -e instructions -n ./a.out             
[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.003 MB perf.data ]
```

But you need to filter out the relevant records and there might be additional records you need to sum up.

```
$ perf script -D | grep PERF_RECORD_READ | grep -v " 0$"
# Annotation by me                              PID    TID 
213962455637481 0x760 [0x40]: PERF_RECORD_READ: 270887 270888 instructions:u 500003881
213963194850657 0x890 [0x40]: PERF_RECORD_READ: 270887 270889 instructions:u 2000001874
213964190418415 0x9c0 [0x40]: PERF_RECORD_READ: 270887 270890 instructions:u 4000002175
```

Comment: Are the HW counters virtualized separately for each thread?  e.g. would it be possible for one thread generate 9999 `mem_inst_retired.split_loads` events, but another thread to actually trigger the event and get the sample with just 1 misaligned load in that thread?  (Shouldn't be an actual problem in most cases, especially for a very frequent event like `instructions`, I'm just curious how it works under the hood; whether just the sample-recording is per-thread or also the HW counters saved/restored on context switches between threads of the same process.)

Comment: I believe the whole event state is bound tightly to a task and switched during context switches (see [perf_event_context_sched_out](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/df561f6688fef775baa341a0f5d960becd248b11/kernel/events/core.c#L3499) ). You can also just count events for a long time without even generating overflow interrupts and Linux should make sure that you only get the count from the selected pid.

Comment: @Zulan Did it worked with -p as well? I mean by providing PID of a running process?

Comment: @Zulan `perf report -T` does not work with -p, it seems! However, combing your second solution with the first one gave me the best result:

`perf record -s -e <my events> -c 1000000000 -p <myprocesses>`

... and for parsing:
`perf script -D | grep PERF_RECORD_READ | grep -v " 0$" | grep <event name>`

Comment: Yes, I don't think it's possible with `-p` to follow newly spawned child processes. I was assuming that you could influence the initial spawn of the application.